# Unsolved: Omniauth-facebook not offering email from facebook api 2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I have a Ruby on Rails facebook login setup with my webpage, using omniauth-facebook 1.4.1 (not using Devise), and facebook api 2.4.  Though the login works, I cannot retrieve the email or user_birthday using scope.  I've searched all posts on this, and it remains unsolved for me.

In my initializer, /config/intializers/omniauth.rb,

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', :scope => 'email', info_fields: 'email,name', :display => 'popup'
end
```

In my /models/user.rb,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.sign_in_from_omniauth(auth)
    find_by(provider: auth['provider'], uid: auth['uid']) || create_user_from_omniauth(auth)
end

def self.create_user_from_omniauth(auth)
    create(
        provider: auth['provider'],
        uid: auth['uid'],
        name: auth['info']['name'],
        first_name: auth['info']['first_name'],
        last_name: auth['info']['last_name'],
        image: auth['info']['image'],
        email: auth['info']['email']
        )
end
end
```

My controllers/sessions_controller.rb,

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    #session[:omniauth] = auth.except('extra')
    user = User.sign_in_from_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
end

def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    session[:omniauth] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
end

end
```

For every attempt of a solution I've re-set my server, did rake db:drop db:create db:migrate.  I check my db and the name, uid, and image link is stored, but not email...  Also: on Facebook, under the "status and review" side-tab, I have "YES" for the "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?", enabling email, public_profile, and user_friends.

I've tried downloading omniauth-facebook 2.0.1, also.  Not sure what to do, please help:).  This seems like a common problem people may have...

Comment: I have noticed this behavior myself. @Emu , could you please elaborate? Is there an article or official documentation you can point to which confirms that Facebook no longer provides user emails?

Comment: Using scope, email should be available, according to facebook documentation,...

Comment: @Emu, that’s just nonsense.

Comment: API v2.4 limited what fields will be returned by default, additional fields now need to be specifically asked for – see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes, “declarative fields”. That means, the API request made to request the user details needs to be modified accordingly. If your framework does not expose that request to you, then you will have to ask the people who wrote it to adapt their code.

Comment: @CBroe You're just implying this is an Omniauth issue in not being up to date with the current API v2.4 change(s)...  I only hope others aren't having this same issue, it seems like a huge deal to me